# JmDNS doesn't resolve: Error writing DNS result to client

Tags: android, proxy, listener, host, jmdns

I get the following output in my logcat when trying to resolve JmDNS services. What does it mean?

```
03-05 15:12:07.947    1170-3248/? W/DnsProxyListener﹕ GetHostByAddrHandler: Error writing DNS result to client
03-05 15:12:07.947    1170-3248/? W/SocketClient﹕ write error (Broken pipe)
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue right now ... did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: I stopped using JmDNS because I could never get it to work properly (actually I don't think it works properly at all). I recommend that you use mdnsjava instead which has worked flawlessly for me. Give it a try!